# Is there any way to pass the parameter value to Yajra datatable? Please see the code below

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

//Controller

```
public function admin_dashboard(CollectionDataTable $dataTable1)
{
       $from = $to = date('Y-m-d');

       $dataTable = $dataTable1->with('from',$from)->with('to',$to)->html();
       return view('operation.admin_dashboard',compact('from','to', 'dataTable'));
}

public function get_collection_table(CollectionDataTable $dataTable,Request $request)
{
    //$from = $to = date('Y-m-d');
    return $dataTable->with($request->all())->render('operation.admin_dashboard');
}
```

//In route

```
Route::get('/ahsdashdgasdhadgas', 'Operation\BillingDepartmentController@get_collection_table')->name('ahsdashdgasdhadgas');
```

//Yajra Datatable

```
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
        ->addTableClass('table table-bordered table-secondary table-hover')
        ->setTableId('collection-table')
        ->columns($this->getColumns())
        ->postAjax([
            'url' => route('ahsdashdgasdhadgas'),
            //'type' => 'get',
        ])
```

}

I can not access the parameter in datatable. Anyone help me to pass parameter in the datatable route so that I can use the parameter for query?

Comment: I am not so sure as to what you are trying to accomplish. Could you update your question with additional information?

Comment: $dataTable = $dataTable1->with('from',$from)->with('to',$to)->html();

public function get_collection_table(CollectionDataTable $dataTable,Request $request)
{
    return $dataTable->with($request->all())->render('operation.admin_dashboard');
}

Route::get('/ahsdashdgasdhadgas', 'Operation\BillingDepartmentController@get_collection_table')->name('ahsdashdgasdhadgas');

How do I pass the parameter in the Yajra data table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I pass the parameter in the Yajra data table??

You could make use of the `data` option

```
$builder->postAjax([
    'url' => route('users.index'),
    'data' => 'function(d) { d.key = "value"; }',
])
```

[Documentation](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/html-builder-ajax)

---

*Side note*: You are using `postAjax` but your endpoint route type is `GET`.
Hence you may need to change your route type to `POST`

```
Route::post(
    '/ahsdashdgasdhadgas',
    'Operation\BillingDepartmentController@get_collection_table'
)->name('ahsdashdgasdhadgas');
```

OR instead of `postAjax` use the `ajax` method of the builder

```
$builder->ajax([
    'url' => route('users.index'),
    'type' => 'GET',
    'data' => 'function(d) { d.key = "value"; }',
])
```

Comment: How to send this data from controller and how I use it in query?

Comment: What do you mean _from controller_ ? You would send data _to the controller_ and then process it and send an appropriate response.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how I send data to the controller and then process it?

Comment: You send data to the controller as mentioned in the answer and obtain it in the controller using the request object `$request->key`

Comment: I think I am irritating you a bit as I am new to this.

public function admin_dashboard(CollectionDataTable $dataTable1)
{
       $from = $to = date('Y-m-d');

       $dataTable = $dataTable1->with('from',$from)->with('to',$to)->html();
       return view('operation.admin_dashboard',compact('from','to', 'dataTable'));
}

public function get_collection_table(CollectionDataTable $dataTable,Request $request)
{
    return $dataTable->with($request->all())->render('operation.admin_dashboard');
}

How can I use the parameters from and to? Please help.

Comment: @WoarakaBeenMahbub Great! Please share how have you managed to solve it as an answer.

Comment: $datatable = $dataTable1->html()->postAjax([
            'url' => route('get_collection_table'),
            'type' => 'post',
            'data' => ['from'=> $from,'to'=>$to],
        ]);

I use it from the controller and it works.